# Formulario html a php

Tags: php, html

A lo mejor lo que pregunto es absurdo. Tengo un form en html, y lo quiero enviar a un archivo .php Otras veces, lo que he hecho, es tener un form en un php y lo mando a un php, pero en esta ocasion es de un .html a un .php.

```
<form action="donar.php" method="POST">
                <div class='col-lg-3 '>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="date" id="fecha" name="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class='col-lg-3 '>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="time" id="hora" name="">
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class='col-lg-3 '>
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <label for="detalles">Detalles:</label>
                            </td>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <textarea name="detalles" id="detalles" cols="20" rows="1"
                                    placeholder="¿Algun detalle?"></textarea>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class='col-lg-3 '>

                    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviarDonar">
            </form>
```

Y mi archivo php es este

```
<?php

if (!isset($_POST['fecha']) && !empty($_POST['fecha'])) {
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}

if (!isset($_POST['Hora']) && !empty($_POST['Hora'])) {
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}

$fecha ="";
$hora ="";

$fecha=strip_tags(trim($_POST['fecha']));
$hora=strip_tags(trim($_POST['Hora']));

?>
```

Al darle a enviar, me salta Notice: Undefined index: fecha in... Se que el input de html, devuelve un objeto. La variable, esta vacia, hago un empty y esta vacia. Mi problema, es que ya no se si no llega el dato a php, si al ser un objeto no se tratarlo, no se cual es mi problema.

Comment: Para que desde PHP puedas leer los valores que llegan por tu form, debes leerlos por medio de su atributo `name` y en este caso tu no tienes ningún valor `fecha` asígnado ahi

Comment: es decir lo pusiste en el `id` lo que deberías hacer es que cada input, tenga en el atributo `name` el valor en forma de texto por el cual deseas recuperar

Comment: omg, lo siento por la pregunta absurda. Llevo sin tocar php mucho, y estoy mezclando php con js, con el getElementByID... acostumbrado al id... Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siempre que quieras capturar datos en PHP desde HTML se necesita el valor que va dentro del atributo de **name=""** en tu caso no lo ponías y por eso te daba error, por que PHP no encontraba que asignarle a la variable

```html
<form action="donar.php" method="POST">
  <div class='col-lg-3 '>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="fecha">Fecha:</label>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="date" id="fecha" name="fecha" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-3 '>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="hora">Hora:</label>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="time" id="hora" name="hora" required>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-3 '>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <label for="detalles">Detalles:</label>
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <textarea name="detalles" id="detalles" cols="20" rows="1" placeholder="¿Algun detalle?"></textarea>
          </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class='col-lg-3 '>
    <input type="submit" value="Enviar" id="enviarDonar" name="enviar">
</form>
```

Código PHP:

```html
<?php
if (!isset($_POST['fecha']) && !isset($_POST['hora'])) {//Si fecha u hora vienen vacios, redirigirlos al index
    header("Location: index.html");
    exit;
}
if (isset($_POST["enviar"])) {//Solo si le dieron click al boton enviar
    $fecha = strip_tags(trim($_POST["fecha"]));
    $hora = strip_tags(trim($_POST["hora"]));
    if (isset($_POST["detalles"])) { //Como el campo no es requerido, solo en caso de que seteen asignaremos a la var
        $detalles=strip_tags(trim($_POST["detalles"]));
    }
    echo "Fecha: $fecha<br>Hora: $hora<br>Detalles: $detalles";//Solo para imprimir
}
?>
```